# Creating a Xamarin.Android project using .NET 6

Tags: xamarin.android, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

How would I create a `Xamarin.Android` project that targets .NET 6 (Xamarin.Android being the traditional Android bindings, not .NET MAUI)?

Creating a new project from the Visual Studio 2022 UI generates the same Mono template Visual Studio 2019 does.

This [guide](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/guides/OneDotNetBindingProjects.md) seems to suggest manually editing the .csproj file, but doing that breaks the build with errors like:

> Package Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat 1.3.1.3 is not compatible with monoandroid50 (MonoAndroid,Version=v5.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade your Visual Studio to Visual Studio 2022 preview.

Version: Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.1.0 Preview 4.0

After that you could create Android project with .Net 6.0.

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's great! Do you happen to know when this feature will be out of preview?

Comment: Update: as of Visual Studio 2022 17.3.2 this feature is available out of preview!

Comment: Is it available also for Xamarin.Forms?